# What components do I need to install in order to use Oracle graph for analysis?

Tags: oracle, oracle-graph

What components do I need to install in order to use Oracle graph for analysis?
I want to build it either on the cloud or on-premise, are there any differences?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/22.1/spgdg/oracle-graph-server-and-client-installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Oracle Graph (property graph feature) in three ways:

1. Oracle Database + Graph Client
2. Oracle Database + Graph Server + Graph Client
3. Graph Studio of Oracle Autonomous Database

Option 1 and 2 work both on cloud and on-premises without any difference, while Option 3 is available only on Oracle Autonomous Database.

Please also see the references below. Thanks!

---

- How to setup Oracle Graph on always free tier cloud services
  https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbpm/r/livelabs/view-workshop?wid=686
- Getting Started with Graph Studio (using always free tier)
  https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbpm/r/livelabs/view-workshop?wid=758
- Build Oracle Graph on Docker
  https://medium.com/oracledevs/build-oracle-graph-on-docker-part-1-2-5fcacaca430e
- Oracle Graph Server and Client Installation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/22.1/spgdg/oracle-graph-server-and-client-installation.html